# Mediapipe Interaction with GUI program through gesture recognition not detected

Tags: python, opencv, gesture-recognition, mediapipe, haar-classifier

I currently had a working example of a custom haar cascade object detection where the users fist would be used to navigate through the programmed GUI components with arrow shapes through the menu pages, however for an assignment I have to convert this to a mediapipe example that would detect the fist drawing circles on each index point and navigating through the menu in the same way. I'm currently stuck as to how I'm calling the gesture recognition to interact with the menu and not too sure what I need to add or remove from the program after a few iterations. Sorry if this is a really newb example I am completely new to mediapipe, python and opencv simply using them for one assignment.

```
# Fist hand function
def detect_fist(image):
    # Image convert to RGB
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    results = hands.process(image)

    # Are hands in the image
    if results.multi_hand_landmarks:
        for hand_landmarks in results.multi_hand_landmarks:
            # Check if the index and middle fingers are extended
            if (hand_landmarks.landmark[mp_hands.HandLandmark.INDEX_FINGER_TIP].y <
                    hand_landmarks.landmark[mp_hands.HandLandmark.MIDDLE_FINGER_TIP].y):
                return True
    return False


while camera.isOpened():
    # Main Camera
    ret, frame = camera.read()

    if ret:
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


        # Draws circle landmarks onto the videocapture
        def draw_landmarks(image, landmarks):
            for landmark in landmarks.landmark:
                x, y = int(landmark.x * image.shape[1]), int(landmark.y * image.shape[0])
                cv2.circle(image, (x, y), 5, (0, 255, 0), -1)


        # Draw landmarks on the image
        results = hands.process(cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
        if results.multi_hand_landmarks:
            for hand_landmarks in results.multi_hand_landmarks:
                draw_landmarks(frame, hand_landmarks)

                fist_pos = hand_landmarks.landmark[mp_hands.HandLandmark.INDEX_FINGER_TIP]
                thumb_pos = hand_landmarks.landmark[mp_hands.HandLandmark.MIDDLE_FINGER_TIP]
```

```
if detect_fist(frame):
            for (fist_pos, thumb_pos) in landmarks:
                cv2.putText(frame, "Fist detected!", (50, 50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (255, 0, 0), 2)
                dx = (fist_pos.x - thumb_pos.x)
                dy = (fist_pos.y - thumb_pos.y)
                if change_menu == "" or change_menu == "variable":

                    for i in range(len(menu_components)):
                        x_shape_start = menu_components[i]['startEnd'][0]
                        y_shape_start = menu_components[i]['startEnd'][1]
                        x_shape_end = menu_components[i]['startEnd'][2]
                        y_shape_end = menu_components[i]['startEnd'][3]
                        if (x_shape_start < dx < x_shape_end) and \
                                (y_shape_start < dy < y_shape_end):
                            if i < 6:
                                act = i
                            else:
                                if i == 6:
                                    act = "back"
                                elif i == 7:
                                    act = "next"
                        elif change_menu == "number":
                            for i in range(10):
                                x_shape_start = numbers_menu[i][0]
                                y_shape_start = numbers_menu[i][1]
                                x_shape_end = numbers_menu[i][2]
                                y_shape_end = numbers_menu[i][3]
                                if (x_shape_start < dx < x_shape_end) and (
                                        y_shape_start < dy < y_shape_end):
                                    # Number Acknowledgement
                                    # menusound.play(1)
                                    # menusound.wait()
                                    temp_code += str(i)
                                    change_menu = ""
                                    selected_bool = True
```

I will also include a pastebin link to the full code here: https://pastebin.com/PjEGhmQ5

Any guidance is greatly appreciated and please feel free to call me a newb if its something really obvious!

Thanks in advance and take care :)

I've tried to use mediapipe fist recognition to be detected by the camera and navigate through the custom made GUI, it draws the circle landmarks around the fist however does not interact with the menu items at all.

Comment: What will I do with gui?

Comment: So it opens the camera and when a fist is detected it will print from the menu components on the canvas drawn as rectangles with opencv such as "Hello World" or numbers onto the console, it also has arrows to navigate between different pages of the menu for multiple options as it is supposed to allow someone to write a program from the GUI, the pastebin definitely gives a better example of the full code.

Comment: Yes. I saw gui with yellow arrow.. Btw, I don't see medioapipe nor opencv.

Comment: you mean in the codeblocks above? yes they don't show the imports but the pastebin does?

Comment: from pastebin dosen't work. Only gui is showing.

Comment: I just updated it please let me know if this works for you, if not is there another way i may share this? thanks for your time! https://pastebin.com/Mw3J4A5V

Comment: I still had problem using Linux. And my friend still had same problem using Unbuntu. We both had same AMD64. I had another Raspberry Pi 4 B using Linux, same issue.